# Android Webview freeze on lock screen

Tags: android, webview

I am working with audio website for webview app,
problem is the app freezes when phone screen is lock is on due to the `onPause` method i am using:

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mWeb.onPause();
    mWeb.loadUrl("about:blank");
}
```

Now if I don't use `mWeb.loadUrl("about:blank");`, then the music keeps running in background

If I use it and the phone goes in sleep mode, the app freezes

How can I solve this where app should not freeze when the lock screen shows and also so the music does not play when the app is closed?

Comment: Did you try to change the order of the commands? To call super.onPause at the very end.

public void onPause() {
   mWeb.loadUrl("about:blank");
   mWeb.onPause();
   super.onPause();
}

Answer (score 1):

I used `pauseTimers()` method to stop video/audio from playing in the background in the `onPause()` method of the activity.And then in `onResume()` method I used `resumeTimers()` and `WebView.onResume()` method to webview freezing. Also, I'd suggest don't use "about:blank" in `onPause()` instead in `onDestroy()` method of the activity. Here's my complete implementation:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopVideo();
    webview.pauseTimers();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    webview.resumeTimers();
    webview.onResume();
}

private void stopVideo() {
    try {
        Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
                .getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null)
                .invoke(webview, (Object[]) null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
        webview.destroy();
        webview = null;
    }
```